# Use an integer sequence as `x` in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, grouping

In R, with the default `plot` function, if you pass it just one variable, then it assumes it is the `y`-variable, and that `x` variable is just a sequence from `1:length(y)`. I'm looking for a way to replicate this with ggplot2, but with the ability to group and facet by other variables.

For example, I can fake it with the `iris` dataset:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=rep(1:50, 3), y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) + geom_line()
```

[image: iris as timeseries]

But in general, I have data that does not have the same number of samples in each group, so there is no neat way to cheat like this. Is there a way to do this generally?

Answer (score 1):

Following code will give you same plot without need to worry about number of samples in each group:

```
iris2= iris
library(data.table)
setDT(iris2)
iris2[,new:=1:length(Sepal.Length),by=Species]
ggplot(iris2, aes(x=new, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species, group=Species)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Even more succintly `iris2[, new := seq_len(.N), by = Species]`

Comment: The same place `.SD` is defined, within `?data.table`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're getting at, you can do this if you have, or can create, an index that is the same for corresponding measurements in different groups. For example:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(3)
dat = data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=20),
                 value=c(rnorm(20,10,2), 5*rnorm(20,10,2), 10*rnorm(20,10,2)),
                 index=rep(1:20,3))

# Create different missing values of dat$count for each level of dat$group 
# (this corresponds, for example, to a case where you haven't necessarily measured 
# all groups on each measurement occasion)
dat[c(3:5,10,15,22,37:39,44:46,50,55:58), "value"] = NA
dat

# Plot by group
ggplot(dat, aes(x=index, y=value, colour=group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

On the other hand, if you don't care about correspondence between groups but just want to plot observations of three different groups (of arbitrary lengths) on the same graph (I'm coming up empty on a real-world use case for this), then you can create separate indices for each group as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(3)
dat = data.frame(group=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",10),rep("C",15)),
                 value=c(rnorm(5,10,2), 5*rnorm(10,10,2), 10*rnorm(15,10,2)))

# Add index
dat = dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(index=1:n())

ggplot(dat, aes(x=index, y=value, colour=group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: The real-world use-case is checking out the behaviour of a time-series after a particular type of event. In my case, looking at soil drying after rain (the groups are already defined, using cumsum(rain) as the group ID).

Comment: But then you'd want the index (time, in this case) to correspond across groups. What I meant in the second example is that you assign the index without regard to whether it has any meaning or any correspondence across different groups.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out a way to do what I want:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=unlist(by(Sepal.Length, Species, seq_along)),
                 y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  geom_line()
```

Which produces the same graph as in the first question, but doesn't require *a priori* knowledge of the group structure.